# how to create mysql view with REGEXP

Tags: mysql, regex, view

My table.value is varchar. It contains string like '...totalValue:xxxx,...`. Now I want to create a view which extract xxxx from`value` and convert it to number as a column of the view.

maybe something like this?

```
create view v_data  
as select  
    value REGEXP `.*,totalValue:(.*),.*` (1).toNumber as totalvalue  
from table;
```

thanks very much!!!

Comment: You cannot do that (with `REGEXP` since it returns booleans only). And that's another reason why normalization rocks

Comment: then is there any way else I can achieve this? maybe something like reg_replace in mysql?

Comment: Probably `LOCATE` + `SUBSTR`

Answer (score 0):

If you can create a select that gives you the correct answer then you can also create a view of that select.

To extract parts of a string use [`substr`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_substr). To find out the start and end positions to use in substr use [`locate`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_locate) with ':' and ','.

```
select substr(test, locate(':', test) + 1, locate(',', test) - locate(':', test) - 1) from test;
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e3849/6)

Comment: Thanks very much! I know how to get the answer!

Comment: NP. Welcome to stack overflow. Remember to mark the correct answer as correct and to up vote any helpful answer.